# Laravel site isn't working in live server

Tags: laravel, autoload

The root structure of my project as below:

[image]

The index.php

[image]

The line highlighted is the own throwing error:
[image]

I'm lost on how to fix this. Apparently the autoloading isn't working but not sure how to fix as the path are correct.
I also removed vendor folder and ran: `composer install, composer update and then composer dump-autoload.`

What else to do. My local is loading fine. Only live site. I also ran this:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Make sure that the php version on server matches the on you local machine. Same for composer version

Comment: Yea, I checked that too. My server supports 7.4 and my composer 7.2^|8.0^. So should be  compatible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to laravel/public directory and copy all the folder ,past outside the public folder. then change the path in index.php file. if your project  on serve in the directory like public_html/laravel/ do this
require **DIR**.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
if your project in public_html/ then
require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: I did that actually as you can see in the index.php above

Comment: replace equire DIR.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: check the path of root directory and autoload.php file

Comment: $app = require_once DIR.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php'; I updated wrongly value for this  in index.php